# Start an if statement according to the message RECEIVED-Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have created a bluetooth chat,I want to make changes as such that I want to perform an action if the

`if(messageRecieved.equals("message required"){
 //Action
}`
I do not know which statement is the above mentioned messageRecieved
ref-:https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat

Comment: Post you complete code here

Comment: here is the link could not send entire code-:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat/tree/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothchat

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Zakir-Check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `BluetoothChatFragment.java` add your logic inside `handleMessage(Message msg)` where the UI fragment receives the message from the service:-

```
case Constants.MESSAGE_READ:
    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
    if(readMessage.equals("message required")){
        mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName + ":  " + readMessage);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: will let you know in a minute

Comment: and I think I should add .getBytes to the code
if(readMessage.equals("message required").getBytes()){

Comment: Worked!,sorry for the stupid questions,that's my lack of sleep asking